# How to replace line breaks that are not after a specific character?

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I need to process a csv file but one of the fields contains line breaks.

How can I replace all line breaks that are not after the double quote character (") with space? Any solution with awk, perl, sed etc is acceptable.

The file that is in the form:

```
497,50,2008-08-02T16:56:53Z,469,4,"foo bar 
foo

bar"
518,153,2008-08-02T17:42:28Z,469,2,"foo bar
bar"
```

The desired output is:

```
497,50,2008-08-02T16:56:53Z,469,4,"foo bar foo  bar"
518,153,2008-08-02T17:42:28Z,469,2,"foo bar bar"
```

Comment: This may be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  You have not indicated what you're trying to accomplish.  If you want to read the data in a program, the correct solution is to use a CSV parsing tool that handles the line breaks.  In fact, even for the task as stated, use a Perl CSV parsing module.  It understands how to deal with CSV strings containing line breaks.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I understood your question to be a request to replace intra-field newlines (even if they occur immediately after a `"`, such as in a field containing `␊foo` or `foo "bar"␊baz`). The following achieves that:

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my $qfn_in  = ...;
my $qfn_out = ...;

open(my $fh_in,  '<', $qfn_in)  or die("Can't open \"$qfn_in\": $!\n");
open(my $fh_out, '>', $qfn_out) or die("Can't create \"$qfn_out\": $!\n");

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 2 });
while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh_in) ) {
   s/\n/ /g for @$row;
   $csv->say($fh_out, $row);
}
```

I think it would make more sense to use the following:

```
for (@$row) {
   s/^\s+//;   # Remove leading whitespace.
   s/\s+\z//;  # Remove trailing whitespace.
   s/\s+/ /g;  # Replaces whitespace with a single space.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed but the question is'nt clear enough to know what to do with a line like

```
497,50,2008-08-02T16:56:53Z,469,4,"truc biz",test

sed ':A;/[^"]$/{N;bA};y/\n/ /' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Its fairly easy to match the fields in csv.

The framework is the stuff between *quoted/non-quoted fields*
and is either delimiter or end of record tokens.

So the framework is matched as well to validate the fields.
After doing that, it's just a matter of replacing linebreaks in quoted fields.
That can be done in a call back.

The regex `((?:^|,|\r?\n)[^\S\r\n]*)(?:("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"[^\S\r\n]*(?=$|,|\r?\n))|([^,\r\n]*(?=$|,|\r?\n)))`

Here it is in Perl, all in one package.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;

sub RmvNLs {
   my ($delim, $quote, $non_quote) = @_;
   if ( defined $non_quote ) {
      return $delim . $non_quote;
   }
   $quote =~ s/\s*\r?\n/ /g;
   return $delim . $quote;
}

my $csv = <DATA>;

$csv =~ s/
     (                                  # (1 start), Delimiter (BOS, comma or newline)
          (?: ^ | , | \r? \n )
          [^\S\r\n]*                         # Leading optional horizontal whitespaces
     )                                  # (1 end)
     (?:
          (                                  # (2 start), Quoted string field
               "                                  # Quoted string
               [^"\\]* 
               (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
               "
               [^\S\r\n]*                         # Trailing optional horizontal whitespaces
               (?= $ | , | \r? \n )               # Delimiter ahead (EOS, comma or newline)
          )                                  # (2 end)
       |                                   # OR
          (                                  # (3 start), Non quoted field
               [^,\r\n]*                          # Not comma or newline
               (?= $ | , | \r? \n )               # Delimiter ahead (EOS, comma or newline)
          )                                  # (3 end)
     )
   /RmvNLs($1,$2,$3)/xeg;

print $csv;


__DATA__
497,50,2008-08-02T16:56:53Z,469,4,"foo bar 
foo



bar"
518,153,2008-08-02T17:42:28Z,469,2,"foo bar
bar"
```

Output

```
497,50,2008-08-02T16:56:53Z,469,4,"foo bar foo bar"
518,153,2008-08-02T17:42:28Z,469,2,"foo bar bar"
```